# Fill in zeros from data of past week (168 indexes prior) in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, missing-data

I have data of electricity usage. During the power outrages the data is '0'. 
I want to replace those 0's with the data of same time during the past week. Which is 168 indexes ahead or behind in the dataset.

In the below code, I am saving the index of all the zeros. Running a loop which will place the value that lies 168 indexes ahead in the dataset at the current index.

```
Index_Zero = data[data["Total"]==0].index.to_list() #Output = list of indexes where all the zeros lie

print(Index_Zero[0]) #Output = 2

for i in Index_Zero:
    data.loc[(Index_Zero[i]), 'Total']=data.loc[(Index_Zero[i+168]), 'Total']
```

Also, if I print

```
data.loc[(Index_Zero[0]), 'Total']=data.loc[(Index_Zero[2]), 'Total']
print(data.loc[(Index_Zero[0]), 'Total'])
Output: 0.0
```

DataSet:

```
           Date         Time     Total
0     23-Jan-2019  12:00:00 AM  18343.00
1     23-Jan-2019  01:00:00 AM  18188.00
2     23-Jan-2019  02:00:00 AM      0.00
3     23-Jan-2019  03:00:00 AM  23394.00
4     23-Jan-2019  04:00:00 AM  20037.00
```

Comment: What part of this is not working for you?

Comment: The for loop is not working. It gives an error list index out of range.

Comment: did you try the answer I posted?

Comment: Yes. Its iterating 6 times and then gives an error list index out of range. Although its getting the data and printing it. Still the original dataset is not changed.

Comment: It seems that for some value (possibly the last) the +168 index doesn't exist because the data is limited. Can you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the range of for loop. It was iterating beyond the list.

```
Index_Zero = data[data["Total"]==0].index.to_list()
for items in range(0, len(Index_Zero)-1):
    data.loc[(Index_Zero[items]), 'Total'] = data.loc[(items+168), 'Total']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, a more natural solution is to:

- Set the index to "true" *datetime*, derived from *Date* and *Time* columns.
- Run a loop over indices of rows with *Total == 0*.

  - Retrieve the value from a row with index 1 week back.
  - Save this value as *Total* in the row with current index.
- Finally reset the index to what it was before.

To perform this, run:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time), inplace=True)
for ind in df[df.Total.eq(0)].index:
    df.loc[ind, 'Total'] = df.loc[ind - pd.Timedelta('1W'), 'Total']
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Note that the loop must be based **only** on indices, not on full rows.
The reason is that power outage could occur at particular weekday and hour
e.g. in 2 (or more) consecutive weeks.

So a loop based on full rows (*for ... in df[df.Total.eq(0)].iterrows():*)
would retrieve always **original** *Total* values (it would not see the
update from one week, while processing a row for the next week (assuming
that both these rows contained initially *0*)).

**Another remark**

Assuming that your rows are ordered by *Date* / *Time*, your original code
should:

- Refer to the current index **minus** 168 (one week **before**,
  not **after**).
- The mentioned subtraction od *168* should be done from the current
  index (*Index_Zero[i]*).

So this fragment of code should actually be *data.loc[(Index_Zero[i] - 168), 'Total']*.

But my solution is resistant to any missing rows in the DataFrame,
so I advise to take my solution.

Comment: File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 438, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1547604000000000000

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  File "C:\\TestApp\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)


  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 440, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc
KeyError: Timestamp('2019-01-16 02:00:00')

Comment: First, first index of zero is 2. So thats why I went for 168+i.
Second, I dont know how pd.TimeDelta will figure out number of rows in a week. How can we make it so its just fetches the value from i+168 and replaces it in the current index.

Comment: *TimeDelta* does not need to know the number of hours in a week. Expression like *ind - pd.Timedelta('1W')* locates a row with index just 1 week before the current Date / Time, actually - before the index value generated from Date / Time of the current row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is the problem. You are replacing the value of `data.loc[(Index_Zero[i]), 'Total']` as the value at index(i+168) in the Index_zero list which is always 0. (You maintained the list exactly for that). I think this is an innocent mistake.

Change your code to this

```
Index_Zero = data[data["Total"]==0].index.to_list() #Output = list of indexes where all the zeros lie

print(Index_Zero[0]) #Output = 2

for i in Index_Zero:
    data.loc[(Index_Zero[i]), 'Total']=data.loc[(i+168), 'Total']
```